# Play remote audio with react-native-audio-recorder-player and RNFetchBlob not working on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, rn-fetch-blob

I'm working on a **React Native** app where I need to load an audio file from the backend and play it in the app.

For this I'm using the packages **[RNFetchBlob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob)** and **[react-native-audio-recorder-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player)**.

The problem is that my implementation works perfectly on **Android**, but it doesn't work on **iOS**... Even for playing files that were recorded using the **[react-native-audio-recorder-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player)** inside **iOS** itself.

When playing files downloaded using **[RNFetchBlob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob)** I get the following error:

```
FigFileForkOpenMainByCFURL signalled err=2 (errno) (open failed) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMediaFramework_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Sources/Platform/Darwin/DarwinFile.c:576
```

The part of the code that matters:

```js
import AudioRecorderPlayer from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

// THIS IS A SAMPLE, NOT THE REAL URL AND TOKEN.
const fileRemoteUrl = 'https://my-backend.com/files/file-id';
const authToken = 'my-authtoken';

// could be 'mp3' or 'aac', etc...
const fileExtension = 'm4a'; 

const dir = NFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir;
const path = `${dir}/${Base64.btoa(fileRemoteUrl)}.${fileExtension}`;

const res = await RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: false,
    appendExt: fileExtension,
    path,
}).fetch('GET', fileRemoteUrl, { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` });

const internalUrl = `${Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' : ''}${res.path()}`;

const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
await audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(internalUrl);
// here the audio should start playing,
// but I get the error on the device(simulator) console (xcode output)
```

As I said before, the same code **works like a charm** on **Android**.
Any idea how to solve this problem? I'm stuck in this...
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that the problem was in this line:

```js
const internalUrl = `${Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' : ''}${res.path()}`;
```

For both **iOS** and **Android** it is necessary to add the prefix "**file://**" to the file path before passing to the "*startPlayer*" method.

The reason I was previously only adding the prefix on Android is because I use the same code snippet to load files of other formats (not audio). And for example to use the component "*<Image source={{ uri }} />*" on **iOS** the uri cannot have the prefix.

So the solution was to create a specific treatment to add the prefix when the platform is **iOS** just before calling the "*startPlayer*" method.